# Unable to load native library on 4.2 4.3 but loads on recent versions

Tags: android, android-ndk, native-activity

I've a native android app (`NativeActivity`, no java code but only `libMyApp.so` native library)

The app runs perfectly on Android 5.0.1 and 5.1.1 but crashes on android 4.3 and 4.2.2

For 5.0.1 and 5.1.1 versions load the `.so` lib successfully from

- `/data/data/com.example.myapp/lib/libMyApp.so`

4.3 and 4.2.2 versions try to load from one of following locations

- `/data/app-lib/com.example.myapp-1/libMyApp.so`
- `/data/app-lib/com.example.myapp-2/libMyApp.so`

The error message is

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapp/android.app.NativeActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to load native library: /data/app-lib/com.example.myapp-2/libMyApp.so
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method
```

My app has a single shared library i.e. doesn't depend on third party libs.

And the module name is specified in manifest file like this

```
<meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name"
           android:value="MyApp" />
```

The `libMyApp.so` is linked with `-llog -lGLESv3 -lGLESv2 -lGLESv1_CM -lEGL -landroid -lz` libs.

Why the lib cannot be loaded, what I'm missing ?

Why old android versions do not load from `/data/data/com.example.myapp/lib/` ?!

Does the older android versions have another module naming convention ?

Comment: Check logcat for messages from the dynamic linker.

Comment: @fadden There is no any linker message. Is there a linker logging level which can be elevated to and how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 days of research I finally managed to find the source of issue.

Firstly somehow Native App doesn't show full linker error in logcat - (**I don't know why!**)

But after converting the same app to Java/JNI app, I was able to see following linker error only on Android versions prior to L (5.*).

> dlopen("/data/app-lib/com.example.myapp/libMyApp.so") failed: dlopen
>   failed: cannot locate symbol "srand" referenced by "libMyApp.so"...

I used to compile the cpp code with android-21 api level from r10e ndk.

Which basically doesn't guarantee that the app will run OK on android version prior to L.

Here is the official android [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77004) .

As in my native app `OGLES3.1` features are used, I cannot downgrade the target SDK level from 21, so I had no choice than updating min sdk level to 21.

Comment: The error message is returned by `dlerror()`, not written directly to the log. You saw it with a Java app because the VM logs the failures. (Sorry, I forgot that part when I asked you to check the logs earlier.)

Answer (score 0):

have you load your library in your class like this?

```
static {
        System.loadLibrary("nativeLib");
    }
```